# How to format the remaining disk space as FAT32 from Windows 7/Vista

Tags: external-hard-drive

I want to use my external hardrive in my PS3 but it needs to be formatted to FAT32. I've tried, but only 30GB was formatted so how do I format the remaining space?

Answer (score 1):

Grab [this Live CD](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/livecd.php). Burn it. Attach the external drive to your computer and boot up into the GParted Live CD.

You'll get a graphical interface with which to format the disc as you choose.